# Define how an external drive is mounted at the drive level (Linux)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, external-hard-drive, mount

By editing `/etc/fstab` I can define how a particular external drive gets mounted on a particular computer. However, suppose that I plugin the drive in a different computer - is there a way of defining the properties of how a drive gets mounted on any system *at the drive level* (i.e. it gets carried within the drive, not a particular OS's configuration)?

Comment: I suspect that differences in distributions will fight against you.  Depending on the kind of Linux, even if the system were using disk labels as a key for the mountpoint, some linuxs would put it at `/mnt/DISKLABEL` and others at `/media/DISKLABEL`, others just `/mnt/sdc1` regardless, so you'd never get a consistant path everywhere.  Don't know what your ultimate goal is, but if you want to your software find your disk after mounting, consider finding it by UUID

Comment: Some filesystems (namely: ZFS) are somewhat like this, but most aren’t.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. As stated by *infixed* you can still find you external drive device file using symlinks from `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` or `/dev/disk/by-partuuid/` and associated mountpoint from there using [`lsblk`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsblk) if you want (not always installed).